# What is the difference between "I don't believe you?" "I don't believe in what you are saying?"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 I don't believe you.
>
> 2 I don't believe in what you are saying.

Comment: We wouldn't normally include ***in*** in #2. We usually only use that "phrasal verb" form when referencing a specific "thing" that we don't believe ***exists***. Thus *I don't believe **in** God* means *I don't believe God exists,* whereas *I don't believe God* with no preposition means *I don't believe **the claims made by God*** (I think He is either mistaken or lying).

Comment: And She often is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two differences to separate out here. There is the difference between "believe" and "believe in", and the difference between "you" and "what you are saying".

*"Believe in"* usually refers to sets of ideas, like religion, or classes of things that may exist or not, such as ghosts or afterlife.
Assuming that isn't what is meant here, I'm reframing the question:

What is the difference between "believe you" and "believe what you are saying"?

1a *I don't believe you.*
This is a direct statement that might mean you don't believe someone in general, or that you don't believe what they just told you. It could even be an accusation of lying.

2a *I don't believe what you are saying.*
This is more limited, and may not mean that you are accusing someone of lying. It may just mean that you think the person is wrong.

However, there is overlap between the two senses.